# How do react hooks reference values passed to the array of dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Say I have this component, with  the following hook:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
useEffect(
    () => {
        //....code
        if (props.propOne === ....) { .... }
        // ...code
        if (props.propTwo === ....) { .... }
    }, 
    [props.propOne]
)

return <Something />

}
```

The above hook will run

- once on the first time the component code gets executed
- every time the value of `props.propOne` changes

Notice however that the hook callback also makes a reference to `pros.propTwo`, without actually having it passed to the dependencies array.

While `props.propTwo` will never factor in whether the hooks gets re-executed, what happens to the value of it that the hook callback references inside its body?

for example

- During initial component rendering `props.propOne === A` and `props.propTwo === B`
- The hook gets executed and references values `A` and `B`
- During a subsequent rendering `props.propOne === C` and `props.propTwo === D`
- The hook gets re-executed, since `props.propOne` changed. It references value `C` for the `props.propOne` but what does it reference for the `props.propTwo` value? `B` or `D`?

Does the hook reference values based on the closure created on component execution or does React do some voodoo where it only keeps the updated value for values passed to the dependencies array?

From the docs:

> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the callback. Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every value referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies array.

UPDATE:

After asking the question I fell unto this article, by Dan Abramov:

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

I suggest everyone to read it.

Comment: Surely the simple solution is to include props.propTwo in the dependencies then, if as you say 'While props.propTwo will never factor in whether the hooks gets re-executed...' ?

Comment: Yes, but this was not the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React hooks` rely heavily on `closures` to make use of values. The values that are referenced within the hook will be the values that were present in the closure of useEffect when it was last called.

For instance, in your example if `props.propOne` is changed and in the subsequent render props.propTwo is changed, the value of `props.propTwo` inside the `useEffect` callback will the previous value since useEffect is not executed when `props.propTwo` changes.

If however, you are updating `props.propOne` and `props.propTwo` together, then the value inside `useEffect` hook will be the updated one.

Considering your case where the `props.propOne` and `props.propTwo` are changed together and trigger a render, the value of `props.propTwo` will be `D` inside `useEffect` callback

Comment: This seems to validate my own understanding then. Thanks.